# Why does assignment with loc not work despite matching indices and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I can't reproduce this simply, but I'm in a situation where I have dataframes `df` and `substitute` and

```
display(df.loc['Book'].index)
display(df.loc['Book'].columns)
display(substitute.index)
display(substitute.columns)
df.loc['Book'] = t
```

shows the same thing twice,

```
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='somename')
Index(['0', '0.5', '1'], dtype='object')
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='somename')
Index(['0', '0.5', '1'], dtype='object')
```

yet the assignment in the last line assigns only `NaN`s. What could I be doing wrong? Everything works as it should when I do `df.loc['Book'] = t.values`

Comment: it will help if you createa a small(sample) dataframe as well to replicate your question

Comment: Without a sample dataframe, it's hard to reproduce and understand what you are asking for.